# Using venue tips and photos in third party app and combining data - permitted?

Tags: foursquare, rules

I am having trouble understanding the foursquare Terms of Use concerning the Venues API.

I am making an application that has a SQLite database integrated. The database has a single table that contains around 300 trainstations with their coordinates and station ID. I am manually mapping these stations to a foursquare ID, and putting foursquare ID in the same table.

Then, when I "show" the specific station in my application, the app knows which ID to use when asking the Foursquare API for tips and photos.

The Terms of Use states that I can't combine data from other databases.

Am I permitted to make an application, that collects photos and tips for the specific station with this method?

From the Terms of Use

" You can associate external content with foursquare venues, but you cannot combine foursquare venue data with other location databases or export your own location database that violates these terms."

"We do not allow services to combine foursquare data with their own or third party location databases such that they learn about new places or alter place metadata based on foursquare."

Any help greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're welcome to layer foursquare data on top of your POI database, or to add foursquare data on top of foursquare's POI database. What you're not allowed to do is combine the two POI databases -- i.e. have your own set of train stations, supplemented by other train stations retrieved from foursquare. Your usage of tips and photos is fine -- just remember to properly attribute foursquare when using its data!